# Comparing Definitions of Moore space.

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, homology-cohomology

Here is the definition from Marty Arkowitz book "Introduction to Homotopy Theory" :

> [image]

---

But my professor wrote it as the following:

Moore space for $G$ in dimension $n>1$ is a CW complex $M$ s.t.
$$ \widetilde{H_{k}}(M;\mathbb{Z})\cong \begin{cases} 
      G & if  k = n \\
      0 &  otherwise. 
   \end{cases} $$

**My questions are:**

$1$- I think $1$-connected means the same as simply connected .... am I correct?

$2$- Why my professor put $\mathbb{Z}$ in the definition? when I asked him he said it must be $\mathbb{Z}$ but I do not know why and he was in a hurry. Could anyone explain this for me, please?

Comment: 1) Yes. Your professor’s definition is incorrect because it leaves out this condition; as written it’s satisfied by integer homology $3$-spheres. 2) That’s just what the definition is. In the first definition the $\mathbb{Z}$ is implicit.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I do not understand the part of your first statement that says "as written it's satisfied by integer homology 3-spheres " ..... could you please explain why?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Also I do not understand why "In the first definition the $\mathbb{Z}$  is implicit " could you please explain that for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment:

1. Yes, $1$-connected means simply connected.
2. $H_i(X)$ means $H_i(X, \mathbb{Z})$ by definition.

Both definitions have small errors in them: in Arkowitz's definition he should either be talking about reduced homology or otherwise excluding the case $i = 0$, and your professor's definition is missing the simply connected condition. Without that condition the definition is satisfied by [homology spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_sphere) such as the [Poincaré homology sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_sphere#Poincar%C3%A9_homology_sphere), which are not simply connected and are not [Moore spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_space_(algebraic_topology)). However, genuine spheres $S^n$ are Moore spaces $M(\mathbb{Z}, n)$ for $n \ge 2$.

Comment: Why Arkowitz definition must exclude the case $i=0$?

Comment: @Smart20: the definition read literally is requiring zeroth homology to vanish when $i=0$, which is impossible.